# trying to make hash table, program compiles but keeps crashing

Tags: c++

I am trying to make hash table, with a class hash that stores string `name` and int `age` into tables which are linked list(non standard).
The `table` array of `item` pointers stores the head of each linked list.
Adding an item involves updating the last item of the linked list with input `name` and `age`.
There aren't any compilation errors but it crashes unexpectedly. I suspect my `hash::add_item` function as creating a hash table(constructor of hash) and function `int hash::pos` work just fine (i've checked).
 here is my code-

hash.h

```
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H
#include <string>
using std::string;
class hash{
public:
    const static int table_size=10;
    struct item{
        string name{"none"};
        int age{};
        item* next{nullptr};
    };
    item* table[table_size];
    hash();
    ~hash();
    void add_item(string a,int b);
    int pos(string a);
    item* last_ptr(item* a);
};
#endif // HASH_H
```

hash.cpp

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
void hash::add_item(string a,int b){
    int p=pos(a);
    if(table[p]->age==-1){
        table[p]->name=a;
        table[p]->age=b; return;
    }
    else {
        item* ptr=new item;
        ptr->name=a;
        ptr->age=b;
        ptr->next=nullptr;
        last_ptr(table[p])->next=ptr;   
    }
}
int hash::pos(string a){
    int sum{};
    for(char x: a){
        sum+=x;
    }
    return sum%table_size;
}
hash::item* hash::last_ptr(item* a){
    if(a->next){
        return last_ptr(a->next);
    }
    return a;
}
hash::hash()
{
    for(item* x: table){
        x=new item;
        x->name="none";
        x->age=-1;
        x->next=nullptr;
    }
}

hash::~hash()
{
}
```

and main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "hash.h"
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
int main(){
    hash h1;
    h1.add_item("abc",20);
    h1.add_item("xyz",30);
}
```

Comment: In the `hash` constructor, try changing the loop to use references: `for(item*& x: table){.....`

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful but why raw pointers?

Comment: `warning C26495: Variable 'hash::table' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).`

Comment: Your code will have memory leaks unless you delete all the allocated pointers in the destructor.

Comment: In `add_item` you dereference `table[p]`, but none of the `table_size` elements of `table` has ever been initialized. There are most likely more problems elsewhere.

Comment: *There aren't any compilation errors but it crashes unexpectedly.* -- I wonder why so many say "it compiles ok, but...".  It makes no difference if the program compiles ok, but there are logical errors.  All compiling ok means is that the program has no syntax errors, nothing more than that.  Whether the program has logical errors is a totally different issue.

Comment: @everyone I'm sorry, I think I've messed up a lot .

Comment: I had a plan to initialize all tables in the constructor of hash, but I wasn't using pass by reference. Thanks Johnny Moop and everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor does not allocated the items: It takes a copy of each item in the table
and replaces the value of the copy by a newly allocated item.
Try:

```
hash::hash()
{
    for(auto &x : table){
        x=new item;
        x->name="none";
        x->age=-1;
        x->next=nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003 This is just fixing the constructor but as other replied you shall avoid using `new ` and `delete` and rely on `unique_ptr` and `std::vector` so that you code will not leak.

Comment: I'll take the advice. Thanks!